# Is it possibly to clear the clipboard when LibreOffice is being closed?

Tags: xfce, clipboard, libreoffice

I'm running XFCE on Linux Mint.
Sometimes I copy & paste potentially sensitive data inside LibreOffice Calc or Writer, which shouldn't exist anymore inside the clipboard once I exit those programs.

Is there a way to automatically erase the clipboard when LibreOffice is being closed?

Comment: Quite generally if you run X Server it provides the standard system clipboard available to applications under Linux. You could access that piping a blank into either `xsel -- input` or `xclip --in` from a script whose execution should be conditionned on LO closing.